# Master Detail MVVM with Prism and XAML binding view in data context

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I have the following dummy application where I'm trying to build a Master Detail with two views. The first is the collection view, which I can successfully select an element of and it displays in the Content Presenter Data Template with the TextBlock and TextBox defined as they are below.

I have tried to Move the TextBlock and TextBox out to a view, but have been unsuccessful at getting it to display the data. If I remove the TBs and uncomment the view, it will display the view but the TBs in the view won't populate.

Of course, the idea is that I will have more than one type.

**MainWindow**

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/" 
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <views:CollectionView DataContext="{Binding myItemCollection}">
        </views:CollectionView>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Detail" Content="{Binding myItemCollection.SelectedViewModel}">
            <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:TextViewModel}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"></TextBox>
                        <!--<views:TextView/>-->
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentPresenter.Resources>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**TextView**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Views.TextView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/" 
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Text Item"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I think item is not getting inside the "myItemCollection.SelectedViewModel"  check this first.

Comment: I'd start with removing `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"` from your `TextView` - data context needs to be inherited in your `DataTemplate` in order for the bindings to work.

Comment: @Grx70 That seems to have worked. If you want to turn that into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"` attribute from your `TextView`.

What it does is it pulls the appropriate view model from the container and assigns the view model to `TextView.DataContext`. On the other hand in your template you do not explicitly pass the templated data to the `TextView` control, so it's expected to be inherited via automatic inheritance of `DataContext`. But that does not work, because `TextView.DataContext` is explicitly set by `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"`.

In case it is required to use view model auto wiring you can always set this attribute from referencing scope, that is in XAML in which your view is "used", e.g.:

```
<StackPanel>
    <views:TextView prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" />
</StackPanel>
```